# What is functional data?

Tags: machine-learning, panel-data, functional-data-analysis

Let's say I run a separate regression on different cross-sections at each point in time t. I would then have a time series for each regression coefficient over different periods in time. Would this data be considered functional data? Can I use k-means clustering on it?

If not, does anyone have any other suggestions on how I can look at structural changes time series data with panel data? Also open to ML techniques.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=structural+change+time+series

Comment: I am no expert but this looks like functional data to me. But then your question is very broad. There are whole books on functional data analysis.